# autoplay and looping video

Tags: html, laravel, video

I've put a video on my website. I want it autoplay and loop when the page is open.
This is what I put on my code:

```
<video style="width:100%;" height="" autoplay loop>
    <source src="/public/slide/MUffest Fashion show cut to cut_1 (1).mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

the looping works perfectly but the autoplay didn't seems work. then, if i put 'controls' method, it didn't play automatically, only if i click the video. but if i remove it, it only show a black blank page. what should i do? is there something wrong on my code?

Comment: Nothing wrong I guess, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)"_Note: Sites that automatically play audio (or videos with an audio track) can be an unpleasant experience for users, so should be avoided when possible._" ... "_In some browsers (e.g. Chrome 70.0) autoplay doesn't work if no muted attribute is present._" Their autoplay guide can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)

Answer (score 4):

I've already figure it out, that Chrome does not allow to auto play video with sound on. So I have to add `muted` attribute on video tag. so my final code looks like this:

```
<video style="width:100%;" height="" muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="/public/slide/MUffest Fashion show cut to cut_1 (1).mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```